# Как создать эффект дёргающейся кнопки на CSS?

Tags: css3, html, css

Делаю кнопку с дёргающимся эффектом, как на  [сайте](http://tinvest.org/9steps).
Скопировал код анимации для кнопки, но кнопка не работает.

Как можно создать такую же кнопку?

Comment: Так всегда будет, если копировать код. Посмотрите css3 animation / keyframes.

Comment: @Etki, спорный вопрос, копировать красивый эффект и настроить его под себя вполне нормальная практика, но в любом случае разобраться как это работает необходимо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А кейфреймы скопировали?

Вот, с сайта примера они

```
<style type="text/css">
    @-moz-keyframes cycle {
        35% {transform: rotate(0) translate(0, 0);}
        40% {transform: rotate(5deg) translate(0, -2px);}
        45% {transform: rotate(-3deg) translate(0, -2px);}
        50% {transform: rotate(5deg) translate(0, -2px);}
        55% {transform: rotate(-3deg) translate(0, -2px);}
        60% {transform: rotate(5deg) translate(0, -2px);}
        65% {transform: rotate(-3deg) translate(0, -2px);}
        70% {transform: rotate(0) translate(0, 0);}
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes cycle {
        35% {transform: rotate(0) translate(0, 0);}
        40% {transform: rotate(5deg) translate(0, -2px);}
        45% {transform: rotate(-3deg) translate(0, -2px);}
        50% {transform: rotate(5deg) translate(0, -2px);}
        55% {transform: rotate(-3deg) translate(0, -2px);}
        60% {transform: rotate(5deg) translate(0, -2px);}
        65% {transform: rotate(-3deg) translate(0, -2px);}
        70% {transform: rotate(0) translate(0, 0);}
    }
</style>
```

Comment: А как же просто @keyframes?

Comment: Я написал, что скопировал с того сайта. Дальше, думаю, можно погуглить и дописать как нужно уже. =)

Comment: Круто! Спасибо.